# Why did Ego not know this about Earth?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2, eternals

Ego is a Celestial and plans to terraform Earth, as shown in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*.

But another Celestial, Arishem, has made Earth a host planet for the birth of another Celestial, as mentioned in *Eternals*.

Why is Ego trying to terraform Earth when it's a host planet that is about to be destroyed? Considering Ego is a Celestial, wouldn't he know?

Comment: Is Ego a Celestial or is that just what he calls himself? I believe only he calls himself a Celestial and he doesn't look like the other Celestials we know of and is not born in the same manner.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if he knew about it, it's unclear whether the emergence of a new Celestial would have been a problem for Ego's plans.

As explained in *The Eternals*, the unborn Celestial draws energy from the life living on Earth.

> **Ajak:** Five years ago, Thanos erased half of the population of the universe. But the people of this planet brought everyone back with the snap of a finger. The sudden return of the population provided the necessary energy for the Emergence to begin.
>
> **Ikaris:** How long do we have?
>
> **Ajak:** Seven days.

So first of all, given that Ego presumably wasn't planning for the Blip, he probably would have suspected he had longer before the Emergence. In addition the process of terraforming would have killed all life on Earth (and all the other planets he seeded), cutting off the Celestial's food source. The Celestial clearly wasn't immortal either, so it's entirely possible it would have been killed by the process too.

Comment: I think you misinterpret that quote: It does not say, that the blip accelerated the emergence. It sais, that the emergence would have happened 5 years EARLIER without the snap... and only by the blip the halted process had been restarted...

Answer (score 4):

One interpretation would be that Ego simply didn't care. His master plan would have decimated life in the galaxy. So this incarnation of Ego seemed to have little or no respect for life other than his own.